# MySQL. Multiple information into one row

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a question.
For everyone to understand this and an eventual answer I'll just show you.
I have one table that's looking like this:

```
model   | price

model1  |  10
model2  |  15
model3  |  20
model4  |  25
model5  |  30
```

And I want my new table to look like this:

```
                models                  | total
model1, model2, model3, model4, model5  |  100
```

How can I do that? I heard there is a group_concat() function but I also heard that is not indicated to do that. Can someone explain?

Comment: In what way is your desired resultset be more useful to your application than the underlying data?

Comment: @eggyal It's not, I just want to know for my knowledge.

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid I didn't see that when I googled it. Thanks for notifying me.

Comment: @MrSilent if you are going to use group_concat then also read it [*limitations*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) and how to overcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(model) models, SUM(price) total FROM my_table
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/abeaa6/1/0).

But the resulting column is a delimited string, which is obviously less structured (and therefore less useful in software) than an ungrouped recordset.

Comment: OP has shown only sample dataset which is not too big but you should add the brief regarding group_concat limitation if you are suggesting it in your answer